# How to find the limit of this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was trying to figure out the limit of the function below

$a_n = \frac{2^{2n-1}+3^{n+3}}{3^{n+2}+4^{n+1}}$

The answer to the question is $\frac{1}{8}$ but when I divide through by $3^{n+3}$ (because it has the highest power) I cant figure out how they got that answer, Im really stuck has anyone go any hints

Comment: You want the largest base which is $4$, so divide by $4^n$.

Comment: why $4^n$ and not $4^{n+1}$

Comment: The trick with the highest power only works when the numerator and denominator are polynomials, i.e. all the exponents are constant. Here, the exponents are the thing that varies, so that trick is irrelevant.

Comment: It doest matter.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Yeah, thats not the case, it applies. Or maybe I dont understand your comment clearly.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus - I don't think you mean the same thing I mean. The OP needs to determine the terms that dominate. When one is working with polynomials, the "highest power" terms (i.e. the maximum degree terms) dominate. Here, as you point out, the exponents aren't what determines domination, it's the bases.

Comment: but that wouldnt give the answer of $\frac{1}{8}$

Comment: For $n\geq 3$, $4^{n+1} >3^{n+2}$

Comment: the limit as what goes to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_n = \frac{2^{2n-1}+3^{n+3}}{3^{n+2}+4^{n+1}}=$$

$$\frac{(1/2)4^n+(27)3^n}{(9)3^n+(4)4^n}=$$

$$\frac {(1/2)+(27)(3/4)^n}{(9)(3/4)^n+(4)}\to 1/8$$

Answer (score 0):

For such ratios, one should guess first what grows faster. Normally, $a^{k.n\pm l}$, for $a>1$, $k$ and $l$ integers, behaves as $(a^k)^n$.

So with similar fractions, it is often useful to factor both the numerator and the denominator with the biggest $(a_i^{k_i})^{n_i}$ of each.

Finally, you end up with something like

$$\frac{\nu^{n}}{\delta^{n}}\frac{N+o(1)}{D+o(1)}$$
which give you a global behavior. In your case, you can get $\nu=\delta=4$, and $N/D=1/8$.

Answer (score 0):

Look for hidden powers:

$a_n 
= \frac{2^{2n-1}+3^{n+3}}{3^{n+2}+4^{n+1}}
= \frac{2^{2n-1}+3^{n+3}}{3^{n+2}+2^{2n+2}}
$.

The $3^n$ terms are negligible
for large $n$,
so
$a_n 
\approx \frac{2^{2n-1}}{2^{2n+2}}
=2^{(2n-1)-(2n+2)}
=2^{-3}
=\frac18
$.

To check,

$\begin{array}\\
a_n-\dfrac18
&= \dfrac{2^{2n-1}+3^{n+3}}{3^{n+2}+2^{2n+2}}-\dfrac18\\
&= \dfrac{8(2^{2n-1}+3^{n+3})-(3^{n+2}+2^{2n+2})}{8(3^{n+2}+2^{2n+2})}\\
&= \dfrac{2^{2n+2}+8\cdot 3^{n+3})-3^{n+2}-2^{2n+2}}{8(3^{n+2}+2^{2n+2})}\\
&= \dfrac{8\cdot 3^{n+3}-3^{n+2}}{8(3^{n+2}+2^{2n+2})}
\qquad\text{The } 2^{2n+2} \text{ is cancelled out}\\
\text{so}\\
|a_n-\dfrac18|
&= \dfrac{|8\cdot 3^{n+3}-3^{n+2}|}{|8(3^{n+2}+2^{2n+2})|}\\
&\lt \dfrac{|8\cdot 3^{n+3}|}{2^{2n}|8(3^3(3/4)^{n}+2^{2})|}\\
&= \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^n\dfrac{|8\cdot 3^{3}|}{|8(3^3+4)|}\\
&\lt \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^n\dfrac{216}{248}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$